# Transferring live data from an Android app to a Web app

Tags: android, web

First, I am a newbie in Android and I was wondering what would be the best way to transfer data coming from an Android app to a web app.

(The purpose of this is to make an IOT platform for monitoring the environment, and ideally, it would be better if the data on the webpage was live, but I could deal with it if it is not possible)

I am not looking for a very detailed answer, simply some tips to get me started would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following guidelines:

- From your android application, create a service that runs in the background.
- This service will run for example every 30 seconds or however often you want it to update the remote server.
- If the data you are sending to the server must be input from a user, you can perhaps store that data locally while also managing stale data
- Since the service is already running in the background thread, you won't have to worry about affecting the UI thread.
- Now make a HTTP POST request, which will post your data in a JSON string to your server.
- When you get your data in your web application, store them to your database as usual.
- Once stored, you can have a mechanism to check for new data every few seconds and display it.
- There are frameworks that make it very easy to have updates without browser refreshes. Regardless of the framework, you should be able to pull that off easily!

I hope this helps you get an idea!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will try this ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you already have this web app, a simple solution would be to create an android app based in a webview, which is a basic "tool" to work with webpages, allowing your android app to function like a web browser. Until then you cannot gain advantages if comparing this with your basic mobile web browser. The advantages could showup if you produce special designed pages in your web application exactely to be used only inside your android app. For example: simplified design (less, bigger, direct texts; less images, less elements; easy and fast visualization and use) which could represent less bandwidth demand, faster and more productive experience for the user when compared with a normal browser.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will investigate this !

Comment: Rose, please check as correct the answer you think was more helpful to indicate the way of solving your question. Thank you.